# Am I intepreting the repeat signs correctly?

Tags: notation, repeats

So this is a pretty simple question, but I haven't found anything that looks exactly like the piece of music I'm trying to learn, so I have to ask. Am I interpreting the repeat signs in this image correctly if I:

1. Play section 1
2. Go back to the beginning of the piece
3. Play section 1 and section 2
4. Go back to the "right-facing" repeat sign at the beginning of section 2
5. Play section 2 through to the end

[image: simple example with two sets of repeat signs]

Comment: Just wait 'til you get to  "del Segno a Coda"  :-) .

Comment: I think you got the answer you needed, but a tip for the future: add measure numbers. @Richard's answer basically applied that. With measure numbers you will play measures 1,1,2,2. And as Carl Witthoft points out, there are more complex repeat symbols like 'segno' and 'coda'... and 'volta' endings, etc. Listing the exact performance using measure numbers will make those repeats perfectly clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly correct!

Put another way, you'll be performing the numbered sections as "1122" before proceeding to whatever music (if there is any) that succeeds the closing repeat at the end of Section 2.

Comment: Richard, thanks very much. I hadn't even thought of what it would mean if there was more music after section 2 (there isn't in the piece I'm learning), but that extra information makes it even clearer! Thanks again!

Comment: A thought occurred - why have some songs had a repeat sign placed after the clef sign? Seems superfluous - just bad writing?

Comment: @tim I would think it's like a courtesy accidental,not necessary to write because it is implied but is there as a reminder or to make it clearer for the performer.